# DropDownFor changes selected value of SelectedList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a strange problem with DropDownListFor.
I need to create dynamically some selected lists in page, so, i've written this code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < this.Model.RolePermissions.Count(); i++ )
            {
                var item = this.Model.PermissionsList.First(m => m.Text == this.Model.RolePermissions.ElementAt(i).Name.ToString());
                item.Selected = true;

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="holder">
                        <div class="col with-button">
                           @this.Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListId, this.Model.PermissionsList, new { @class = "select2" }) 
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @{ 
                        item.Selected = false;
                    }
                </div>
            }
```

RolePermissions - is IEnumerable, with values, that must be selected in SelectedList
PermissionList - is IEnumerable with all needed values.

So, when page rendered - selection always in 1 selected index.
What am i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so... I was needed to do

```
ModelState.Clear()
```

in controller.